# Do Google Maps API limits apply to Android applications?

Tags: android, google-maps

When I check the website, I see that web application using Google maps API have some limit. 
But what about using it in Android Application?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The official answer from Google:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#usagelimits

The Maps API usage limits apply only to the following APIs:
-Google Maps JavaScript API v2
-Google Maps JavaScript API v3
-Google Maps API for Flash
-Google Maps Image APIs
The Google Earth API, and native Maps APIs for mobile platforms such as Android and iOS are not affected. Use of the embed feature of Google Maps, and other Google products that offer an embed feature that includes a map, are not affected by these limits.

Comment: How about use of private data (ie User/group specific data, password protected) on Google Maps on android?

Answer (score 1):

According to [a post](http://twitter.com/#!/edparsons/status/129513418259574784) by Google Geospatial Technologist Ed Parsons the usage limits do not apply to the native APIs of mobile platforms as Android or iPhone.
Also the pricing table in the [Maps API FAQs](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/faq.html#tos_pricing) does not contain the Android API.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any Google API's like Places, Latitude and etc which are mainly used for Location based services having some limits. As it is provided to general public free of cost its having limitation to certain extends. And this limits are also different for different APIs which you can get to know from your Google's A/c console.